# What algebra is used to simplify this g'(x) equation in the last 2 steps shown below?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

In a high school calculus course homework assignment I'm seeing a problem where the derivative has two main terms, and there is a simplification that doesn't make sense. What algebra rules facilitate this simplification from $-x^2(16-x^2)^{-\frac12}+(16-x^2)^{\frac12}$ to $(-x^2+16-x^2)(16-x^2)^{-\frac12}$?

[image: question_2]

Comment: Factor out $(16-x^2)^{-\frac12}$

Comment: In the future, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math in your questions. The original plaintext math got pretty hairy

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
-x^2(16-x^2)^{-\frac12}+(16-x^2)^\frac12&=-x^2(16-x^2)^{-\frac12}+\underbrace{(16-x^2)^{-\frac12}(16-x^2)}_{(16-x^2)^\frac12}\\
&= (16-x^2)^{-\frac12}(-x^2+(16-x^2))\\
&= (-x^2+16-x^2)(16-x^2)^{-\frac12}
\end{align*}
In the second line you take out the common factor $(16-x^2)^{-\frac12}$.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is really two steps being combined into one. The goal of these steps is to combine the two terms by extracting a like term, $(16 - x^2)^{-\frac12}.$ To do this, first we need to rewrite the second term like this: $$(16 - x^2)^{\frac12} = (16-x^2)(16-x^2)^{-\frac12}$$

Assuming everything is defined, which is always true for the domain of interest, you can justify this with the exponent rule $a^b \cdot a^c = a^{b + c}.$

Now that everything is written in terms of $(16 - x^2)^{-\frac12},$ we can use the distributive property to combine like terms like this:

$$-x^2(16-x^2)^{-\frac12} + (16-x^2)(16-x^2)^{-\frac12} = (-x^2 + 16 - x^2)(16-x^2)^{-\frac12}$$

Hope this helps!